# How to update a bunch of components after a schema change?

Tags: linking

My schema was using a text field whose value was a TCM ID of another related component. Unfortunately, I realized after creating a lot of components that I should have created this relationship using a component link.

I have updated my schema to include a component link while preserving the existing text field.

If you were in my shoes, how would you update these thousands of components?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What Mark says is indeed the way to go - use core services to write a script that does the update for you.

I would work as follows:

- Create a new field in your schema for the component link, and keep the text field
- Build a core service script that does the following

  - get all components that use the schema (using code example below)
  - get the TCM id from the text field value, and use this to update the componentlink field, and save the component
- update any template or code that uses the old field, to use the new field
- finally remove the old field

sample code to get any items using the schema:

```
UsingItemsFilterData usingItemsFilterData = new UsingItemsFilterData();
var itemsUsingSchema = client.GetListXml(tcmID, usingItemsFilterData);  
foreach(item in itemsUsingSchema) //pseudo code, you should parse the xml and get the elements
{
   //open component
   //read value of text field
   //set value of componentlinkfield to tcm id
   //save and check in component
}
```

edit : if you are looking for the core service API documentation, you can find this here :
https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-2301148A-E3EA-43EF-A2FC-7D3C9BAEE8FF

Answer (score 5):

Use the core service to grab the tcmid from the text field and and format the necessary syntax to pop that as the component link directly into the new field.

A few simple Google’s will serve the format/structure you need.